# How to center align a form in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, forms, bootstrap-4

I'm new to Bootstrap and I'm trying to center the form below but currently it is left justified. How can I do this?

Code example:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 no-padding">
    <!-- START CONTACT FROM -->
    <div class="contact-from">
      <form action="assets/php/contact.php" method="post">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email" required />
          <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
          <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" id="subject" placeholder="Enter Your Subject" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
          <textarea rows="6" name="message" class="form-control" id="message" placeholder="Enter Your Message" required></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <button>send message</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <!-- END CONTACT FROM -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand you correctly, you want your form in the center of the div. i believe you have tried entering the bootstrap center class or even the html `<center></center>` tag but didn't do much. this is probably because you have your form in a `<div class="row">` and then a `<div class="col-md-6">`. what this does already is keep the form to the left side of your page. if you wish to retain the row class , write it as

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-12">
            <!-- START CONTACT FROM -->
            <div class="contact-from">
                <form action="assets/php/contact.php" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name" required />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email" required />
                                <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                        <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" id="subject" placeholder="Enter Your Subject">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                        <textarea rows="6" name="message" class="form-control" id="message" placeholder="Enter Your Message" required></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <button>send message</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <!-- END CONTACT FROM -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks - this is really helpful - the only issue is that the first 2 columns are not aligned now as you can see here --> https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ar-F-Ppy8q3_mnCNnxuY8mNsb6Nb?e=xTKHND

Comment: in that case, i have made the necessary corrections to my answer to fix that. you may copy and past the edited version. Don't forget to mark this as the write answer when satisfied.

Comment: sorry but now its back to left justify :( -

Comment: i took out a piece of code that didn't play a major part on my end.. probably because i have additional assets. i've edited it once more to suite your needs.

Comment: Perfection ! - thank You very much !

Comment: i'm glad i could help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bootstrap's flex box classes to center your container by adding only these class to your row div container:

```
 justify-content-center
```

example:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-T584yQ/tdRR5QwOpfvDfVQUidzfgc2339Lc8uBDtcp/wYu80d7jwBgAxbyMh0a9YM9F8N3tdErpFI8iaGx6x5g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div class="row justify-content-center">      
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 no-padding ">
  <!-- START CONTACT FROM -->
  <div class="contact-from">
      <form action="assets/php/contact.php" method="post">
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name" required />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email" required />
              <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-12">
              <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" id="subject" placeholder="Enter Your Subject">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-12">
              <textarea rows="6" name="message" class="form-control" id="message" placeholder="Enter Your Message" required></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12">
              <button>send message</button>
          </div>
      </form>
  </div>
  <!-- END CONTACT FROM -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks - there are 2 issues -- (1) the header of the page is now messed up 
(2) ALL the fonts on the page is now off - reduced in size

Comment: @SamBanerjee Thank you for feedback. 1) Could it be that you copy the cdn link, too? 2) It sounds that in your code is a missing closing tag. maybe missing </small>? Without code or a screenshot is difficult to see what's happend.

Comment: Thanks @Maik - without the cdn link this is not working even though I have bootstrap.min.css in my /assets folder.

Comment: @SamBanerjee It is possible that you share maybe the entire html?

Comment: Sure - please see here -- https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ar-F-Ppy8q3_mnFwT4bz1NVM3lym?e=7wHWME